# Valid `viewName` values for channel's compiled HTML

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

The [API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_getChannelView) for `GET /asset/v1/content/assets/{id}/channelviews/{viewname}` says

```
viewName    string  Required    The name of the asset view to retrieve
```

But doesn't list the valid values, or where to find them.

I've found a `viewName` of `html` works; are there any others?

Comment: Not used this, but I reckon "viewaswebpage" or a variant of it might work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The views are listed [here inside the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/views.htm).  As usual for SFMC documentation, it is buried in a place you would least expect it.

```
"views": {
    "html": {},
    "text": {},
    "subjectline": {},
    "preheader": {},
    "viewAsAWebPage": {),
    "subscriptioncenter": {},
    "forwardHTML": {},
    "forwardText": {}   
  }
```

Comment: Index it before it moves!!!

Comment: "As usual for SFMC documentation, it is buried in a place you would least expect it."  
Never was a truer word spoken! Thanks